# How to add additional actions to a button via a modifier

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

If I have a Button in SwiftUI, how can I add additional actions to that button using a view modifier? For example, let's say I have the following:

```swift
Button("Tap me") {
    print("tapped")
}
```

and I want to write a modifier that we can add to any button, so that when the button is tapped, it also prints "tapped again".

Something like:

```
Button("Tap me") {
    print("tapped)
}
.printWhenTapped("tapped again") // output is "tapped \n tapped again" when button is pressed
```

Assume that the constraint of this problem is you *must* be able to use the native `Button` (i.e. no custom views) and the interface must be like a modifier or button style.

Comment: Try a ButtonStyle not a ViewModifier

Comment: What would you do with a ButtonStyle? I don't think its configuration has access to the button action, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It has an isPressed, you can run an action with that.

Comment: isPressed is just a Boolean value indicating if the button is being held down, it doesn't equate to a button being tapped

Comment: that is as close as you will get.

Comment: Maybe I should specify you can run an action with `.onChange(of: configuration.isPressed)`

Comment: Perhaps keep some state variable to keep track of when the button has been fully tapped using `isPressed`, i.e. a "full tap" only occurs when `isPressed` changes to false after it was just true. This may work, but it feels a little bit hacky.

Comment: or just `guard !newValue else {return}` There is no way to "intercept" an `action` you can put an `onTapGesture` on top of it but it would likely lead to a buggy UI. SwiftUI never behaves well when mixing gestures.

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated

If you want to perform the additional action in response to the button's touchUpInSide event, you can just provide a Button extension:

```swift
extension Button where Label == Text {
  init(_ titleKey: any StringProtocol, action: @escaping () -> Void, additionalAction: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.init(titleKey) {
      action()
      additionalAction()
    }
  }
}

// Usage example:
Button("Tap me") {
  print("tapped")
} additionalAction: {
  print("tapped again")
}
```

For case like printing debug messages during development, you can choose to do like this:

```swift
extension Button where Label == Text {
  init(_ titleKey: any StringProtocol, debugMessage: any StringProtocol, action: @escaping () -> Void) {
#if DEBUG
    self.init(titleKey) {
      action()
      print(debugMessage)
    }
#else
    self.init(titleKey, action: action)
#endif
  }
}

// Usage example:
Button("Tap me", debugMessage: "tapped again") {
  print("tapped")
}
```

If you insist on using view modifiers on the Button (not a custom Button), you may need to use the solution below with DragGesture to determine if the user released a touch inside the button.

For example: record the origin of the touch and compare the distance with button's bounds.

Things will get a little more complicated then. I would just stop here.

---

#### Original

You can observe the button's `configuration.isPressed` like @lorem said:

```swift
extension ButtonStyle where Self == AdditionalActionButtonStyle {
  static func printWhenTapped(_ message: String) -> Self {
    return Self(message: message)
  }
}

struct AdditionalActionButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
  private var message: String

  init(message: String) {
    self.message = message
  }

  public func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label.onChange(of: configuration.isPressed) { _, newValue in
      if newValuw {
        print(self.message)
      }
    }
  }
}

// Usage example:
Button("Tap me") {
  print("tapped")
}
.buttonStyle(.printWhenTapped("tapped again"))
```

If you want to use it as a view modifier, you can wrap it:

```swift
extension View {
  public func printWhenTapped(_ message: String) -> some View {
    modifier(AdditionalActionButtonStyleViewModifier(message: message))
  }
}

struct AdditionalActionButtonStyleViewModifier: ViewModifier {
  private var message: String?

  init(message: String) {
    self.message = message
  }

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content.buttonStyle(.printWhenTapped(self.message))
  }
}

// Usage example: 
Button("Tap me") {
  print("tapped")
}
.printWhenTapped("tapped again")
```

Comment: you might want to test pressing the button and sliding finger off it to cancel the tap and see what happens

Comment: @malhal yes, the additional action will run regardless of whether the touch is released internally or externally.